# Bad State of Stream when reopening an ExpansionTile that's using a StreamBuilder

Tags: dart, flutter

The first time opening the ExpansionTitle, everything is fine. After shrinking and expanding it, I'm receiving a 'Bad State' Stream already listened to, error. I've tried returning the stream as a broadcast, but then after minimizing and reopening, the snapshot is empty. I'm not quite sure what the proper technique is for using an ExpansionTitle with a stream.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
 );
}
}
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
final String title;

@override
 _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
  }
   class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: StreamBuilder(
        stream: _genres(),
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<String>> snapshot) {
          print("snap:  ${snapshot.data}");
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {


              return ExpansionTile(
                title: Text(snapshot.data[index]),
                children: <Widget>[
                  StreamBuilder(
                    stream: _moviemap(index + 1),
                    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                      if (!snapshot.hasData)
                        return Text('No data');


                      List<Widget> items = [];
                      for(String name in snapshot.data) {
                        items.add(
                          ListTile(
                            title: Text(name),
                          )
                        );
                      }

                      return Column(children: items,);
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              );
            });
          } else {
            return Container();
          }
        }),
  ),
 );
}
   Stream<List<String>> _genres() async* {
     yield ['Horror', 'Comedy', 'Drama'];
   }

   Stream<List<String>> _moviemap(int which) async* {
   if (which == 1) {
      yield ['Saw', 'Scary Movie'];
    } else if (which == 2) {
      yield ['Grown ups', 'Grown ups 2', 'Paul Blart'];
    } else {
      yield ['Green Onions', 'Spring Breakers'];
    }
 }
 }
```

Comment: It's hard to answer this question definitively without the stack trace and without knowing what BLoC plugin you're using. Also, please try to shorten the code to a minimum required to understand the issue.

Comment: I'm not using a bloc plugin. The stream being returned from _bloc.allJobsByGroupId is created from yielding the rows from an sqflite database, rather than a controller. I added a bit more code because I wanted to show that I had a nested StreamBuilder, in case that is an issue.

Comment: Movw the code to get the data to `initState` instead of using a StreamBuilder.

Comment: I've updated the code so that it can be easily cut and pasted and throw the same error. @GünterZöchbauer I get that it's possible to make the ExpansionTitle work with a completely different means of state management, but it would invalidate what I'm trying to accomplish using a bloc pattern. At this point, I'm trying to understand why what I'm doing here, doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because following reasons.

1. `StreamBuilder` listens permanently same stream (`_moviemap` in this situation) from `StreamBuilder`'s `initState()` to  `dispose()`.
2. When `ExpansionTile` open and close, it rebuild `children`'s new `StreamBuilder`. And `StreamBuilder` try to listen `_moviemap`. The old `StreamBuilder` have not finished dispose() at that time.
3. The same stream(`_moviemap`) is not allowed to listen more than once.
4. So crashed.

So you should swap `StreamBuilder`'s location and `ExpansionTile`'s location to listen stream(`_moviemap`) once. Good Luck!!

example code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: _genres(),
            builder:
                (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<String>> snapshot) {
              print("snap:  ${snapshot.data}");
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    final title = snapshot.data[index];
                    return StreamBuilder(
                      stream: _moviemap(index + 1),
                      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text('No data');
                        List<Widget> items = [];
                        for (String name in snapshot.data) {
                          items.add(ListTile(
                            title: Text(name),
                          ));
                        }
                        return ExpansionTile(
                          title: Text(title),
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Column(
                              children: items,
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  },
                );
              } else {
                return Container();
              }
            }),
      ),
    );
  }

  Stream<List<String>> _genres() async* {
    yield ['Horror', 'Comedy', 'Drama'];
  }

  Stream<List<String>> _moviemap(int which) async* {
    if (which == 1) {
      yield ['Saw', 'Scary Movie'];
    } else if (which == 2) {
      yield ['Grown ups', 'Grown ups 2', 'Paul Blart'];
    } else {
      yield ['Green Onions', 'Spring Breakers'];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes so much sense.

Comment: While that resolved the issue with expanding and contracting the ExpansionTile, it throws a similar stream already listened to, when the contents of the listview move outside of the visible screen.

Comment: I think that is a problem of architecture of your application. I recommend you as follows.1) Separate your stream from the lifecycle of Widget(eg. using BLoC pattern) 2)Make a Class that bundle necessary data for view. And don’t use nested multiple StreamBuilder, use only one.

Comment: I was able to get it to work by utilizing a ReplaySubject.

Comment: This issue is happened for me with `Wrap` widget, I have a simple `StreamBuilder`, but the dispose is not happened as same time as `new StreamBuilder`, so I use `_vehicleController = new StreamController<Vehicle>.broadcast()` to cheat It. I think It's a bug :(